# How can I get a more clear result for plot of this function?

Tags: plotting, precision-and-accuracy

I use this command

```
f := 128 (1 - 6 x^2 + 
      x^4 + (1 + x^2)^2 Cosh[
        5.883185307179586` x]) Sinh[\[Pi] x]^2 - (-8 (-1 + x^2) Sinh[
       0.20000007` x] - (-3 + x^2)^2 Sinh[
       6.483185377179586` x] + (1 + 
        x^2)^2 (2 Cosh[5.883185307179586` x] Sinh[0.20000007` x] - 
        Sinh[0.20000007` x - 2 \[Pi] x]))^2;
Plot[f, {x, Rationalize[2.35651999, 0], Rationalize[2.35652013, 0]}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 30, PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 6]
```

and this is the plot I get

[image]

How can I get a more clear result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

[`Rationalize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) and simplify the function when defined using [`Set`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) rather than [`SetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html)

```
f = 128 (1 - 6 x^2 + 
        x^4 + (1 + x^2)^2 Cosh[
          5.883185307179586` x]) Sinh[π x]^2 - (-8 (-1 + x^2) Sinh[
          0.20000007` x] - (-3 + x^2)^2 Sinh[
          6.483185377179586` x] + (1 + 
            x^2)^2 (2 Cosh[5.883185307179586` x] Sinh[0.20000007` x] - 
           Sinh[0.20000007` x - 2 π x]))^2 // Rationalize[#, 0] & // 
   FullSimplify;

Plot[f, {x, Rationalize[2.35651999, 0], Rationalize[2.35652013, 0]},
 WorkingPrecision -> 25,
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 MaxRecursion -> 6]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the Help: "Rationalize[x,0] converts any inexact number x to rational form." If I am not mistaken, this is simply wrong. Try e.g.:

```
Rationalize[0.20000007`] // Head
```

You will see that the result is still a machine number (Real, at least in MMA 12.1 on Windows 10).
To improve give an explicit error to rationalize.
Your problem is caused by the subtraction of 2 large numbers. But with an working "Rationalize" we can still do it:

```
mRationalize[x_] := Rationalize[x, 10^-12];
f[x_] := 128 (1 - 6 x^2 + 
      x^4 + (1 + x^2)^2 Cosh[
        mRationalize@
          5.883185307179586` x]) Sinh[\[Pi] x]^2 - (-8 (-1 + 
         x^2) Sinh[mRationalize@0.20000007` x] - (-3 + x^2)^2 Sinh[
        mRationalize@6.483185377179586` x] + (1 + 
          x^2)^2 (2 Cosh[mRationalize@5.883185307179586` x] Sinh[
           mRationalize@0.20000007` x] - 
         Sinh[mRationalize@0.20000007` x - 2 \[Pi] x]))^2;
Plot[f[mRationalize@x], {x, 2.35651999, 2.35652013}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 30, PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 6]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Use a tighter tolerance of `mRationalize[x_] := Rationalize[x, 10^-15];` and you will get radically different results.

Comment: Why do you reference `Rationalize[x, 0]` and then use `Rationalize[x]` in your first comment?